# Java Reading from serial port in Ubuntu

Tags: java, serial-port

I am reading from and writing to a USB serial port in Ubuntu using the standard `/dev/ttyUSB0` file that the operating system provides for me. I do all the hard work in a class that extends Thread:

```
public PacketHandlingThread(String fileName, PacketListener listener)
{
    mListener = listener;

    //the filename points toward a serial port. Something like /dev/ttyUSB0
    try
    {
        mOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        mInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        System.out.println("Created Serial Listener");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The run method looks like this:

```
public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        int numRead = -1;
        try
        {
            while(mInputStream.available() < 1)
            {
                //spin in circles
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                }catch (Exception e) {}
            }

            numRead = mInputStream.read(data);
            System.out.println("Num Read: "+numRead);   
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            numRead = -1;
        }

        if (numRead == -1)
        {
            mListener.OnConnectionClosed();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This code works as expected, but it constantly has to poll the file to see if it has any new data. Instead of that while loop, I would prefer to have something like:

```
synchronized(mInputStream)
{
    mInputStream.wait();    
}
```

But when I do that, it sits there waiting forever, presumably because the underlying stream never calls `notify()` (and there isn't any reason to suspect that it would, I'm just saying I wish it did).

My question is: Is there any way to read from a serial port in a non-polling manner?

I'd really hate to have to use a serial library because my research seems to show that every single one of them is absolutely terrible. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at jUSB: http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/07/06/java-and-usb.html

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Java simple serial connector](http://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/wiki/jSSC_examples) library.

What you need to do is implement a SerialPortEventListener interface as shown in the link above.

We have used it in production, for reading serial data over USB adapter, and it has shown as stable.

Comment: +1 I too use jssc and I am very pleased. You can even hot-plug a USB to serial adapter and it simply works.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, IMHO, if you are writing anything to interface with the lower level (IE device connectivity, hardware implementation, etc...) the best bet would to use **C++** (with GCC for you), as java is finicky when it comes to handling OS level functionality (in most cases, java cannot work with and or has no clear and direct implementation of OS functionality in it's attempt to be cross platform).

If you are calling the base object (which you should as you are reading from it) you can use a for loop to check i against `fileName.size()` instead of testing the stream directly.

```
for(int i = 0; i < filename.size(); i++)
   try{
        //...code here...
      }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
}
```

best of luck,

Comment: 1)  filename is a String containing (in the sample) "/dev/ttyUSB0".  The length (no such thing as `size()`) of that string is a constant.  2)  Even if it were the number of bytes in the file pointed at by the file name, I'm pretty sure this still qualifies as "polling" which is what the asker is trying to avoid.  3)  I don't think you can rely on the size returned by files under `/dev` to be a number of bytes available for reading.